# Extensão php_java não funciona

Tags: php, java

Olá!

Estou com problemas ao chamar uma aplicação java no meu código php, através da extensão php_java:

1) Alterei a configuração no php.ini, e os arquivos estão no endereço descrito na relação abaixo:
[image: descrição do php_java no phpinfo()]

E abaixo o código php, que chama uma classe que fiz para teste, pois precisarei da extensão funcionando para utilizar uma classe de um banco que trabalha com geração de boleto.

```
<?php
    $javaPHP = new Java('TesteJP');
    $javaPHP->set("TEST");
    echo "Java Method = " . $javaPHP->get();
?>
```

Mas ao acessar no navegador, ele retorna uma mensagem como conexão reiniciada, ou e **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET** no rodapé. E ao acessar o visualizador de eventos no servidor, encontro este erro:

```
Faulting application Apache.exe version 2.0.58.200, faulting module
unknown, version 0.0.0.0, fault address 0x01495b58.
```

A cópia da tela do erro está logo abaixo:

[image: Cópia da tela do erro.]

Porém, em alguns momentos em que tento acessar, a página carrega, mas retornando uma mensagem de erro:

```
Fatal error: java() [<a href='function.java'>function.java</a>]: Unable to
 create Java Virtual Machine in H:\Desenvolvimento\sites\abra3\bol.php on 
line 181
```

Comment: poderia simplesmente usar as funções de shell..  exec(), passthru(),, dentre outras

Comment: @DanielOmine, não teria problemas de segurança ao deixar a classe exposta?

Comment: o que seria “deixar a classe exposta”?

Comment: @DanielOmine acessível na pasta do servidor. Configurando pela extensão php_java, as classes ficam em uma pasta que o apache não vê, somente o php.

Comment: via CLI também ...  pode executar pelo exec() a  partir de um local que o “apache não enxerga”..  Alias, o fato do apache acessar o arquivo java implica o quê na segurança?  O importante é que o arquivo java não esteja na pasta pública.

Comment: Se é o mesmo que chamando pelo CLI, tudo bem... Mas ainda assim, minha dúvida é a seguinte: usando o exec() eu não sei como fazer para retornar a informação, coisa que conseguiria através da extensão do java.

Comment: o segundo parametro do exec() retorna o output. O terceiro parametro retorna o status.. http://php.net/exec

Comment: Exemplo: `exec('java arquivo.jar', $output);`. O primeito parâmetro é o comando. Pode escrever um comando como se estivesse num console.

Comment: @DanielOmine entendi. Isto me atenderia com perfeição se a classe que fosse usar em produção tivesse sido feita por mim. É a classe de um banco para cuidar da geração de boletos

Comment: `, que chama uma classe que fiz para teste, pois precisarei da extensão funcionando para utilizar uma classe de um banco que trabalha com geração de boleto.` Nesse trecho entendi que vc faria uma classe java para conectar com classe java do boleto ou da api do banco...

Comment: aliás, ainda pode vc mesmo criar um script em java  para fazer tal comunicação e então no php invocaria pelo exec conforme exemplo..  mas se quer continuar do jeito apresentado na pergunta, parece que falta incluir a classe. Faltou algo como `java_require()`.